# looking for different ways to implement it via python

Tags: python

- Write a simple interpreter which understands "+", "-", and "*" operations.
- Apply the operations in order using command/arg pairs starting with the initial value of `value`.
- If you encounter an unknown command, return -1.

Examples :

- `interpret(1, ["+"], [1])` → 2
- `interpret(4, ["-"], [2])` → 2
- `interpret(1, ["+", "*"], [1, 3])` → 6

```
def len_n(val, command, args):

  if command == '+' :
    return val + args
  elif command == '-':
    return val - args
  elif command == '*':
    return val * args
  else:
    return -1

def interpret(val, command, args):

  count = len(command)

  for i in range(count) :
    val = len_n(val,command[i],args[i])

  return val
*****************

************************
  final = len_n(val,command[0],args[0])
  del command[0]
  del args[0]
  if command[0:]:
    final = interpret(final, command, args)

  return final
****************
```

I tried by above 2 methods both worked as well! what are other methods this can be implemented? Thanks,

Comment: I feel like this would be a better question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and is off-topic on stack overflow

Comment: How should I flag it?

Answer (score 0):

A nice way to solve such arithmetic parsing problems is [Dijkstras shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm), which converts arithmetic expressions written in infix notation (like `(3 + 1) * 6`) into [Reverse polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) (like `3 1 + 6 *`), which has each operator after its operands instead of between them.

Reverse polish notation makes it a lot easier to calculate a result:

```
# Calculates the result of a given arithmetic expression only containing numbers
# and +, * when given in reverse polish notation

outputStack = []

def addNumber(number):
    outputStack.append(number)

def addOperator(operator):
    result = operator(outputStack.pop(), outputStack.pop())
    outputStack.append(result)

def addOperatorByChar(operatorChar):
    if (operatorChar == '+'):
        addOperator(lambda x, y: x + y)
    if (operatorChar == '*'):
        addOperator(lambda x, y: x * y)
    #unknwon operator, don't do anything

#test code:
addNumber(3)
addNumber(1)
addOperatorByChar("+")
addNumber(6)
addOperatorByChar("*")

print(outputStack[0])   #should be 24 in this example
print(len(outputStack)) #should be one after correct arithmetic expression
```